# Examples of ergodic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic

An ergodic process is a process in which the structures of *inter-individual variation* and *intra-individual variation* are asymptotically equivalent [(Molenaar, 2004)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15366359mea0204_1).

In other words:
A process is **non-ergodic** in case results of analysis of inter-individual variation do not generalize to the level of intra-individual change in time, and vice versa.

Equivalently, a process is **ergodic** in case results of analysis of inter-individual variation validly generalize to the level of intra-individual change in time, and vice versa.

I tried to google it but I couldn't find satisfactory and intuitive and easy to understand examples of this process. I'm wondering if anyone could come up with an example to contrast these two processes?

Answer (score 2):

Look at a video of the behavior of, say, an adult male ant for 20 minutes. Would you have noticed if after 10 minutes, the ant was replaced by another adult male ant?

If you wouldn't notice because all such ants behave similarly then the process is ergodic, otherwise [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process#Example_of_a_non-ergodic_random_process).